# A yelow underline in VScode Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Hello Today I opened a VS code and I can see a bug every bracket is yellow and I do not know why.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by upgrading vscode to version 1.67.

You can add the following line into your setting.json:

```
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false
```

This can prevent brackets from changing color.

You can refer to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67#_bracket-pair-colorization-enabled-by-default) for more details about 1.67